# Reportlab page x of y NumberedCanvas and Images

Tags: python, reportlab

I had been using the reportlab NumberedCanvas given at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546511/ . However, when i try to build a PDF that contains Image flowables, the images do not show, although enough vertical space is left for the image to fit. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 13):

See [my new, improved recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576832/) for this, which includes a simple test with images. Here's an excerpt from the recipe (which omits the test code):

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import mm

class NumberedCanvas(canvas.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        canvas.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._saved_page_states = []

    def showPage(self):
        self._saved_page_states.append(dict(self.__dict__))
        self._startPage()

    def save(self):
        """add page info to each page (page x of y)"""
        num_pages = len(self._saved_page_states)
        for state in self._saved_page_states:
            self.__dict__.update(state)
            self.draw_page_number(num_pages)
            canvas.Canvas.showPage(self)
        canvas.Canvas.save(self)

    def draw_page_number(self, page_count):
        self.setFont("Helvetica", 7)
        self.drawRightString(200*mm, 20*mm,
            "Page %d of %d" % (self._pageNumber, page_count))
```

Comment: I modified the above snippet a bit since I don't want to draw directly the total page number but instead make it available from any parts that need it. So I define a placeholder which later been replaced in the above code (akin to [fpdf aliasNbPages](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/aliasnbpages.htm)) - https://gist.github.com/k4ml/7061027